# Android Fingerprint Scanner, detecting the finger used for authentication

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I'm looking to detect which finger is used for device authentication in Android Marshmallow. The callback used for getting the successful authentication is -

```
onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result)
```

However I don't see how can I use the FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult object to detect the finger used for authentication.

Any help is appreciated on this.

Comment: i think theres no such facility provided by android till now.

Comment: yes right @jack jay

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no way to do this, or to hack your way around it. Sorry.

The underlying Fingerprint API is so secure and locked down, and it kind of has to be, as it's data that can be used to open the device and authenticate the user.

Comment: Is this commented in official documentation?

Comment: Any way to do this nowadays, 5 years later, directly through the api or some workaround like root or some sort of a custom rom? There's this thing in MIUI called second space, which implements it. I couldn't find it by myself on the docs, but as I haven't really made anything on android yet so just wanted to make sure. This feature definitely would be so very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

No, i think theres no such facility provided by android till now. so, there is no way to found detecting the finger used for authentication.

Comment: Make this a comment.